# R : C++11 standard requested but CXX11 is not defined

Tags: r, c++11, centos

I am using a **Linux system** *x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library* with a **CentOS server**.
The R version is **3.4.1**

When installing the package "pdftools" I get the following error :

```
Error in .shlib_internal(args) : 
  C++11 standard requested but CXX11 is not defined
```

Has anyone encountered the problem?

Comment: Can you check if `CXX11` is defined within your R environment? If the output of `R CMD config CXX11` is empty, try editing the `Makeconf` in `echo $(R RHOME)/etc/Makeconf` and manually set the variable for `CXX11` to the same value as `CXX`. Then try installing your library again.

Answer (score 1):

Doing the following worked for me:

Under **/usr/lib64/R/etc** there are 2 Makeconf files:

- Makeconf
- Makeconf.rpmnew

Backup the '**Makeconf**' file and replace it with the contents of '**Makeconf.rpmnew**'

Found the solution here (wch's answer):

https://github.com/rstudio/httpuv/issues/82